# on scroll page with iframe inside iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I have a simple video player which is inserted into page within an iframe, now I want when the video player is visible play the video otherwise pause the video. to achieve that am using the intersection observer function.

Here is html skeleton

```
<body>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>

</body>
```

Here is js

```
var configFromParent = null;

window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    var data = event.data;
    if (data.action == "config") {
        configFromParent = data;
    }
    var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) { 
        //console.log(entries);
        if(entries[0]['isIntersecting'] === true) {
            if(entries[0]['intersectionRatio'] === 1)
                document.querySelector("#message").textContent = 'Target is fully visible in screen';
            else if(entries[0]['intersectionRatio'] > 0.5){
                $("#videoplayer")[0].play();
                document.querySelector("#message").textContent = 'More than 50% of target is visible in screen';
            }
            else{
                document.querySelector("#message").textContent = 'Less than 50% of target is visible in screen';
            }
        }
        else {
            $("#videoplayer video")[0].pause();
        }
    }, { threshold: [0, 0.5, 1] });

    observer.observe(document.querySelector(".videoplayer"));

});
```

Now when scrolling my page nothing is happening, but when I change the parent src link to child iframe link everything works perfectly, but I want the iframe to be inside a parent iframe and when the video player is not visible pause the video otherwise play the video

What do I need to do solve this problem?

Comment: basically observer should work with the correct setup. If your testPage. Your skeleton isn't working because iframe cannot load inner html  the way you specified it in sample. To do it correctly  http:/somelink.com/iframe.html  should have  children iframe  in its body

Comment: @GenaMoroz what do you mean? can you help me with this? I spent a few hrs trying to solve this

Comment: updated comment, is it clear ?

Comment: @GenaMoroz yes I know that, it's inside a body, i didn't want to copy all the data here, I thought it's understandable

Comment: ok. I would suggest to get rid of postmessaging to do a clean test, maybe your problem is there.

Comment: @GenaMoroz that didnt help

Answer (score 0):

Observer is totally functional. https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-zhukovsky-chdds?file=/index.html  this sandbox contains  you html setup  (not secure ofcourse). Scroll page down to see how message changes.
Secure frames behave in the same manner. You don't have to worry about it. But don't forget that IE may have no observer, you should handle it. 
And I still assume that the problem in the post messaging